# Using a yield with a next()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a generator that will concatenate each item in a list with each line of a file.

My file `/tmp/list` contains:

```
foo
bar
```

My code is:

```
mylist = [
    'hello',
    'world'
]

def _gen():
    for x in mylist:
        with open('/tmp/list') as fh:
            yield('-'.join([x, next(fh)]))


for i in _gen():
    print(i)
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
hello-foo
world-foo
```

What I was aiming for was:

```
hello-foo
hello-bar
world-foo
world-bar
```

Comment: @PatrickArtner misstyped, fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have one outer loop, and you just grab the *first* line of the file by using `next`.  But you'll want to iterate over the `fh` as well - i.e. there should be *two* loops.

```
for x in mylist:
    with open('/tmp/list') as fh:
        for line in fh:
            yield '-'.join([x, line.strip()])
```

Comment: Yes, it would be.  No problem for large files here.